# Mongoose + GraphQL cannot populate model

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, graphql, apollo-server

Well, I know there are a lot of questions regarding this issue but neither of their solutions worked for me, or I can't find what is happening.

I have a backend server running Apollo Server + Mongoose on localhost. My issue is I can't populate or create the collection since I get:

**Error**: `"ID cannot represent value: <Buffer 5e 38 65 18 f1 e3 f5 43 10 d4 c1 45>"`.

This is the model:

```js
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
const Float = require('mongoose-float').loadType(mongoose);

const gastoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    descripcion: String,
    importe: Float,
    proveedor: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Proveedor'
    },
}, {
    timestamps: {
        createdAt: 'fechaCreacion',
        updatedAt: 'fechaActualizacion'
    }
});

export default mongoose.model('gastos', gastoSchema);
```

This is my type definition:

```js
import { gql } from 'apollo-server';

export default gql`
    type Gasto {
        id: ID
        descripcion: String
        importe: Float
        proveedor: Proveedor
    }

    extend type Query {
        gastos: [Gasto]
        gasto(id: ID!): Gasto
    }

    extend type Mutation {
        crearGasto(descripcion: String, importe: Float, proveedor: ID): Gasto
        actualizarGasto(id: ID!, descripcion: String, importe: Float, proveedor: ID): Gasto
        eliminarGasto(id: ID!): String
    }
`;
```

And this is my resolver:

```js
import Gasto from '../models/Gasto';

export default {
    Query: {
        gastos: () => Gasto.find().populate('proveedores').exec(),
        gasto: (_, { id }) => Gasto.findById(id).populate('proveedores').exec()
    },
    Mutation: {
        crearGasto: (_, input) => Gasto.create(input),
        actualizarGasto: (_, input) => Gasto.findOneAndUpdate(input),
        eliminarGasto: (_, { id }) => Gasto.findOneAndDelete(id)
    }
};
```

#### Attempt 1

I have tried this change on my model definition but it didn't work:

```js
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
const Float = require('mongoose-float').loadType(mongoose);
const ObjectId = require('mongoose').Types.ObjectId;

ObjectId.prototype.valueOf = function() { return this.toString(); }

const gastoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    descripcion: String,
    importe: Float,
    proveedor: {
        type: ObjectId,
        ref: 'Proveedor'
    },
}, {
    timestamps: {
        createdAt: 'fechaCreacion',
        updatedAt: 'fechaActualizacion'
    }
});

export default mongoose.model('gastos', gastoSchema);
```

#### Attempt 2

According to the [mongoose documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) I also tried switching between `populate('proveedores')` (plural), `populate('proveedor') (singular)` but the error changes:

```js
import Gasto from '../models/Gasto';

export default {
    Query: {
        gastos: () => Gasto.find({}).populate('proveedor').exec(),
        gasto: (_, { id }) => Gasto.findById(id).populate('proveedor').exec()
    },
    Mutation: {
        crearGasto: (_, input) => Gasto.create(input),
        actualizarGasto: (_, input) => Gasto.findOneAndUpdate(input),
        eliminarGasto: (_, { id }) => Gasto.findOneAndDelete(id)
    }
};
```

**Error**: `"message": "Schema hasn't been registered for model \"Proveedor\".\nUse mongoose.model(name, schema)"`.

Just in case this is my `Proveedor` model definition:

```js
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const proveedorSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    nombre: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    telefono: String,
    direccion: String,
    email: String,
}, {
    timestamps: {
        createdAt: 'fechaCreacion',
        updatedAt: 'fechaActualizacion'
    }
});

export default mongoose.model('proveedores', proveedorSchema);
```

This is what i am querying on the GraphQL playground:

```
query {
  gastos {
    id
    importe
    proveedor {
      id
      nombre
    }
  }
}
```

Any clues? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Done... nothing changed.

Comment: Please see the answers provided in the linked post. You could also just add a resolver for each `id` field like `obj => obj._id.toString()`

Answer (score 0):

The first argument of `mongoose.model()` must be [the singular name of the collection your model is for. Mongoose automatically looks for the plural, lowercased version of your model name](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html#compiling), so for your case:

```
mongoose.model('Gasto', gastoSchema);
mongoose.model('Proveedor', proveedorSchema);
```

Next you have to add a resolver for the `proveedor` field and `.exec()` to execute the mongoose queries

```
import Gasto from '../models/Gasto';
import Proveedor from '../models/Proveedor';

export default {

export default {
  Gasto: {
    proveedor: ({ proveedor }) => Proveedor.findById(proveedor).exec() 
  },
  Query: {
    gastos: () => Gasto.find().exec(),
    gasto: (_, { id }) => Gasto.findById(id).exec()
  },
  Mutation: {
    crearGasto: (_, input) => Gasto.create(input).exec(),
    actualizarGasto: (_, input) => (_, { id: _id, ...input }) => 
    Gasto.findOneAndUpdate({ _id }, input, { new: true }).exec(),
    eliminarGasto: (_, { id: _id }) => Gasto.findOneAndDelete({ _id }).exec()
  }
}
```

note that the resolver for `actualizarGasto` must be

```
actualizarGasto: (_, { id: _id, ...input }) => Gasto.findOneAndUpdate({ _id }, input, { new: true }).exec()
```